# Towers of hanaoi program in swift

Tags: swift

```
func TOH(n: Int, A: Int, B: Int, C: Int){

    TOH(n: n-1,A: A,B: C,C: B);
    print(A,C);
    TOH(n: n-1,A: B,B: A,C: C)

}
print(TOH(n: 4, A: 0, B: 0, C: 0))
```

This is the logic I had written in swift. When I run it is throwing a "bad access error".
Please someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Xcode comes with a decent *debugger.* Just single-step though your program, and you'll see the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `n==1` case. Try this:

```
func TOH(n: Int, A: Int, B: Int, C: Int){
     if (n == 1){
         print("Move disk 1 from rod " +  String(A) + " to rod " + String(B));
         return;
     }
     TOH(n: n-1,A: A,B: C,C: B);
     print(A,C);
     TOH(n: n-1,A: B,B: A,C: C)
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop?.

Comment: This is a math problem. You can check the java code. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-tower-of-hanoi/

Comment: Indeed your `if` breaks it. Sorry my bad. Do a minor edit so I can retract my downvote.

Comment: It just prints `Move disk 1 from rod 0 to rod 0` multiple times before ending.

Comment: Normally, it has three rods and n disks. Because of the parameters. they are all 0. So that, all of them are the same disk.